# Enviar Email luego de Insert Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Estoy guardando los datos que envió mediante un formulario por medio de Ajax, los datos se guardan correctamente, pero no envía el Email, porque probablemente  no detecta los valores, le estoy pasando los datos al modelo por medio de un array,no se si en eso radica el problema,al tratar de enviar el correo con valores estáticos funciona correctamente, les dejo el código:

**Controlador( C_Calendar)**

```
public function insertar_cita(){


      $data = array(

      'rut_usu'=> $this->input->post('rut_usu'),
      'rut_estu'=> $this->input->post('rut_estu'),
      'id_mot'=> $this->input->post('id_mot'),
      'fecha_ini'=> $this->input->post('fecha_ini'),
      'fecha_ter'=> $this->input->post('fecha_ter'),

         );

   $this->load->model('M_Calendar');
   $this->M_Calendar->insertar_cita($data);

  }
```

**Modelo (M_Calendar)**

```
public function insertar_cita($data){


 $this->db->insert('citas', $data);

//EL problema radica desde las siguientes lineas, aunque se guardan los datos correctamente
//no se envía el correo

 $rut_usu= $data['rut_usu'];

 $query = $this->db->query('SELECT correo_usu FROM usuarios WHERE rut_usu="$rut_usu" ');
 $row = $query->row_array();


 $para = $row['correo_usu'];

 $mensaje='Prueba Local';

 $asunto    = 'Nueva Cita Agendada, SAE';
 $cabeceras = 'From: sae.system@aiep.com' . "\r\n" .
         'Reply-To: remitente@dominio.com' . "\r\n" .
         'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


 mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras);


 }
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#btn_insert").click(function(){

var rut_usu = $("#rut_usu").val();
var rut_estu = $("#rut_estu").val();
var id_mot = $("#id_mot").val();
var fecha_ini = $("#fecha_ini").val();
var fecha_ter = $("#fecha_ter").val();


$.ajax({

 url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "C_Calendar/insertar_cita/",
 type: 'post',
 data: { "rut_usu": rut_usu, "rut_estu": rut_estu, "id_mot" : id_mot , "fecha_ini": fecha_ini , "fecha_ter": fecha_ter},

 success: function(response){ 

       $("#modal_registrar").modal('hide');

       $("#modal_confirmar").modal('show');


      //actualizamos los eventos
       $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

       $("#rut_estu").val("");
        $("#id_mot").val("");
        $("#fecha_ini").val("");
        $("#fecha_ter").val("");
        $("#nombre_estu").val("");

      }

     });
    });
```

Comment: pon estas linea antes de este codigo para que compruebes si los valores a los que envia el email estan bien,
var_dump($para);
var_dump($asunto);
var_dump($mensaje);
var_dump($cabeceras);
mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
Con eso verificas si los datos estan correctos.

Comment: Eso debería colocarlo en la vista verdad? porque si lo coloco en el model no sucede nada

Comment: Puede mostrar tu formulario el codigo html, y tu JS al parecer estas mandando el array de forma correcta.

Comment: La verdad no se que tan necesario seria porque se guardan los datos correctamente, eso quiere decir que los datos enviados están bien. Colocare el AJAX

Comment: Editado, agregue el javascript

Comment: Perdon por tardar, quiza ya lo hayas resuelto, pero no se si este 
$para = $row['correo_usu'];
 esta bien, puedes ahi mismo despues de esa linea poner var_dump($row) y ver si trae el valor correcto

Comment: aun no lo he arreglado....he estado programando otras cosas mientras, el  var_dump($row) no me muestra nada :C

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que probaste que la función mail funciona antes, poniendo campos estáticos. Y como dice Aquiles habría que ver que los parámetros se pasan correctamente y después que la consulta del query devuelve un correo.

Usando codeigniter también tuve problemas al enviar correos, así que si el paso de parámetros y demás esta correcto prueba lo que hice yo, opté por usar la libraria email del codeigniter que creo te facilita un un poco la vida.

```
            $this->email->from(correo_origen);
            $this->email->to(correo_destino);
            $this->email->subject(asunto);
            $this->email->message(mensaje);
            $this->email->send();
```

Recuerda si usas la librería de activarla en por ejemplo autoload.php en la carpeta config. En la parte donde se cargan las librerías: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','email');`

Comment: Si la funcion mail  funcionaba antes con valores estaticos, pense que podría estar mal alguna de estas lineas, ya que soy bien nob, $rut_usu= $data['rut_usu']; o   $para = $row['correo_usu']; probare lo que mencionas

Comment: No funciona, igual gracias por responder :C

Comment: Y las dos variables que mencionas $rut_usu y $para cogen los valores correctos?

Comment: Creo que no, pero no me muestra ningún mensaje de error, puede que sea  eso el problema, aunque si guarda los datos, es porque todos los parámetros son enviados correctamente

Comment: Pon en el modelo un return $para antes de enviar el correo y en el controlador un echo delante de $this->M_Calendar->insertar_cita($data); y dentro del success del ajax un alert(response) o console.log(response) y mira si te devuelve algo. Prueba también para $rut_usu

Comment: No me muestran na O_O lo cual... es raro...

Comment: con ambas variables no te muestra nada? has usado el alert y te sale vacío?

Comment: Si, el alert sale vació

Comment: has probado con el return $rut_usu, cambiarlo por el $para, esta tiene que salir

Comment: Esta vez el alert ni siquiera se ejecuta.

Comment: si sólo has cambiado $para por $rut_usu y antes se ejecutó ahora también debería, si no hay ningúna errata